# Perl match keyword until empty space

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable containing string. I would like to get the string from after `WARD=` until the first empty space (in this example means yyy). I have limited knowledge in regex and pattern matching.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "abc thisis long long stringggggg input=xxx WARD=yyy abcsdasdasd";
chomp($var);
my @ext = $var =~ /\b(WARD)\W+(\w+)/g;
print "@ext\n";
```

Comment: Technically you already have it in capture group 2. See https://regex101.com/r/NGExE7/1 To get a match only, you can use `\bWARD=\K[^=\s]+` See https://regex101.com/r/8uuBYN/1/

Comment: Using word boundary `\b` may give you a false positive match, such as `A-WARD` where `-` counts as a word boundary. If space is your delimiter, and you have no quoted fields which may contain spaces, use space instead. Account for edge case of beginning of line `(?:^| )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pattern:

```
(?<=WARD=)\S+
```

Explanation:

`(?<=...)` - positive lookbehind - assert what preceeds current position matches pattern inside (in place of `...`)

`WARD=` - match `WARD=` literally

`\S+` - match one or more of non-whitespace, so it will match as long as there is no whitespace.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fIUfBd/1)

EDIT

For sake of completeness, I will append @MarcoLuzzara suggestion, which is pattern `WARD=(\S+)`

Here logic changed a little, so let me explain new constructs:

`(...)` - capturing group, which matches pattern inside and stores it inside capturing group.

[Another demo.](https://regex101.com/r/d7fHHU/1)

Comment: Why using a positive lookbehind instead of a capturing group like `WARD=(\S+)`? It is a useless complication and performances are not happy of that.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Are you aware of that cpaturing group also do not have best performance? Also, I do not find lookarounds any more complicated than capturing group. Your comment is purely subjective and it is just you opinion.

Comment: I would say better than positive lookbehind though. Complication in the sense that I do not think it is necessary here and not very performant. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara But to use it, you need to first check for capturing group and their captured value. In my pattern you have what you after as match. No need to additional code.

Comment: Honestly, I do not see the problem for additional code. On the other hand, with a very long string, your regex checks for each letter if the previous five letters are `WARD=`. That seems a performance issue bigger than the additional code to me, With capturing group, the only "major" drawback is that it is stored additional space for the capturing group. I did not downvote your answer because it is correct, but not the one I would use, my opinion of course.

Comment: Both your regexes also match partially, for example `AWARD=foo`.

Comment: Right, thank you for pointing it out @TLP. I was so focused on proving my point on positive lookbehind that I did not go through a full validation of my regex.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
my ($ward) = $str =~ /\bWARD=(\S*)/
   or die("Missing ward);
```

The `\b` prevents `FORWARD=...` from matching.

Comment: The `\b` does not prevent `A-WARD` from matching.